# Tool to find all instances of a class

Tags: c++, code-analysis

I'm working on a C++ project where modules are meant to be combined in a small group to serve a specific purpose (in some sort of processing pipeline).

Sometimes it's hard to know the impact of any change, because we intuitively don't even know all the places where one of our module is being used.

I know I can do Search in Files to find all instances of a class, but is there a tool which can analyze my source code and give me the list of how many instances of each class is used?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of what you are trying to do: `for(...) {A* = new A;}` : how many instances is that ...

Comment: My goal is to be able to get an idea of a potential impact of a change.  For my purpose that would only count as one.  I guess what I'm interested in is how many other modules actually use class A.

Comment: If B inherits from A, presumably you also want to find instances of B?

Comment: I expect you want to know *where* in the other modules that A (B, C,...) is used, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, I might not be understanding your question right, but I believe [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do that:

You will be able to see how everything is being used and called from what. It will give you classes calling what other classes, a whole hierarchy of your code.

Comment: I've used doxygen before but didn't know it could do that... I will check it out again.

Comment: If B inherits from A, grep won't find B.

Comment: ... if there are multiple classes named A (say, in different namespaces), then grep will produce a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

If all the paths through the code is known (very unlikely in reality) then putting a `printf/cout` in the class constructor would do the job nicely.

Otherwise, I would deploy a `find`-and-`grep` solution.